# How do I create a realistic translucent material?

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor

I have been trying to make a material similar to the one in the following photo but didn't get any result that was close enough.

[image]

I tried using a combination of the glass shader and translucent shader but it didn't give a believable result. Anyone has any idea how could I make this procedurally?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're just looking for the frosted glass effect, try something like this. Basically it's just a high transmission value (for transparency/translucency) and a mid-level(ish) roughness (to make it more opaque - "frosted"). I added a bit of subsurface as well, but it's probably not needed. The "Bump Map" setup is optional too, but I just wanted to give some "micro-bumps" on the surface:

[image: RoughGlass]

If you want more transparency (see through it more), you can try this setup. You can control the "frostiness" and transparency/translucency using the IOR of both the Fresnel and the Refraction BSDF, as well as changing the Roughness on the Glass BSDF.

[image: Ball2]

Comment: I'm trying to give it a much more translucent look though, I can't seem to get that right, simply increasing transmission doesn't help.

Comment: What do you mean by _more_ translucent? Do you want to be able to see through it more, or less?

Comment: Yes pretty much

Comment: Which one, more, or less?

Comment: Oh I misunderstood that, I want to be able to see through it more.

Comment: I edited my answer with a second example